# Creating datastore using pyvmomi on ESX

Tags: python, esx, pyvmomi

I am trying to create a VMFS datastore using the devicepath on my ESX host. Based on suggestions from the internet, I tried to use the 'QueryVmfsDatastoreCreateOptions' with devicePath as a parameter and then use the output of the above call (spec) to create a datastore using CreateVmfsDatastore.

I get an error when I try to invoke [QueryVmfsDatastoreCreateOptions](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi/blob/master/docs/vim/host/DatastoreSystem.rst) API

```
[root@localhost bin]# python dd_esx_disk.py -s 10.25.190.100 -u root -p Abcd123! --uuid eui.3221784b198087db8ccb707400000001
Device path: /vmfs/devices/disks/eui.3221784b198087db8ccb707400000001
Unexpected error: _InvokeMethod() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Code:

```py
def createDatastore(si, uuid):
    devicepath="/vmfs/devices/disks/"+ uuid
    print "Device path: %s" %devicepath
    try:
        vmfs_ds_options = vim.host.DatastoreSystem.QueryVmfsDatastoreCreateOptions(devicePath=devicepath, vmfsMajorVersion=5)
    except vim.fault.NotFound:
        print "Not found"
    except vim.fault.HostConfigFault:
        print "host config fault"
    except vmodl.fault.NotSupported:
        print "Not supported"
    except Exception as e:
        print "Unexpected error: %s" %e

    else:
        print "Query success"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can find an example [here](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples/pull/269/commits/532b13bc4745c26d6c246d4c53c48dda56fcbe0b).

The short version:

A `ManagedObjectReference` to a `HostDatastoreSystem` needs to be supplied when you use `vim.host.DatastoreSystem.QueryVmfsDatastoreCreateOptions()` to create a datastore.

Comment: does any one have working example code for creating vmfs datastores using pyvmomy?